# How can I get a proxy list to work with selenium properly? (python)

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

The funny thing is I'm not getting any errors running this code but I do believe that the script isnt using a proxy when it reloads the page. here's the script

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    proxy_list = input("Name of proxy list file?: ")
    proxy_file = open(proxy_list, 'r')
    print ('Enter url')
    url = input()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chop)
    driver.get(url)


    import time

    for x in range(0,10):



        import urllib.request
    import time



    proxies = []

    for line in proxy_file:
        proxies.append( line )
        proxies = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in proxies]

        while True:
                for i in range(len(proxies)):
                    proxy = proxies[i]
                    proxy2 = {"http":"http://%s" % proxy}
                    proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxy2)

                    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
                    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
                    urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
                    time.sleep(5)
                    driver.get(url)
                    time.sleep (5)
```

Just wondering how I can use a proxy list with this script and have it work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, its almost impossible to make selenium work with proxy on Firefox & Chrome. I tried 1 day and nothing. Opera I didnt try, but possible will be the same.

Also I saw freelancer request like "I have a problem with proxy on Selenium + Chrome. I'm the developer and lost 2 days to make it work,but nothing as result. If you don't know sure how to make it working good, please dont't disturb me -- its harder than just copy-paste from internet."

**But its easy to do with Phantom JS -- this feature is working good there.
So try to do needed actions via PJS.**